# Confusion regarding partial derivative chain rule

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations, chain-rule

Consider the multivariable function $P(x,t) = te^{-x^2}$. I would like to introduce a new variable $z = x-\mu t$, for some $\mu \in \mathbb{R}$. Let $Q(z,t) = P(x,t)$ in the new coordinate system. I am interested in calculating the quantity $\partial Q/\partial t$, but I am having some conflicting results.

In terms of the new coordinates, $Q(z,t) = te^{-(z+\mu t)^2}$, so computing the derivative explicitly gives

$$
\frac{\partial Q}{\partial t} = e^{-(z+\mu t)^2}\bigg[1-2\mu t(z+\mu t)\bigg]
$$

However, in my specific application, I would like to able to compute $\partial Q/ \partial t$ using the chain rule. Since $Q = Q(z,t)$, wouldn't the derivative just be

$$
\frac{\partial Q}{\partial t} = \frac{\partial Q}{\partial z}\frac{\partial z}{\partial t} = -\mu\frac{\partial Q}{\partial z} = 2\mu t(z+\mu t)e^{-(z+\mu t)^2}
$$

Clearly, the two answers are different, but I can't figure out why the second method with the chain rule doesn't work.

Comment: Your question isn't really making sense. It seems you want to take a _total_ derivative with respect to $t$, not a partial, else I'm not sure what you are computing when you write $$\frac{\partial Q}{\partial t} = \frac{\partial Q}{\partial z} \frac{\partial z}{\partial t}$$ Applying the chain rule to $Q$ should be $$\frac{dQ}{dt} = \frac{\partial Q}{\partial z} \frac{\partial z}{\partial t} + \frac{\partial Q}{\partial t}$$

Comment: Let me rephrase: I have a PDE for $P(x,t)$ and I'm trying to make this variable substitution so that the PDE is in terms of $z$ and $t$ only. I have to calculate $\partial Q/\partial t$, $\partial Q/\partial x$, and $\partial^2 Q/\partial x^2$. Would it be correct to say that since $x = z + \mu t = f(z,t)$, we have $\partial Q/\partial x = \partial Q/\partial z \cdot \partial z/\partial x + \partial Q/\partial t \cdot \partial t/\partial x$? If so, we can also say $t = f(x,t)$ so that $\partial Q/\partial t$ follows a chain rule as well.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you have a PDE in $P(x,t)$, you want to make a coordinate transformation $x \to z+\mu t$, then you want to convert the PDE in $P$ into a new PDE in terms of $Q(z,t)$? If so, you don't want to compute $\partial Q/\partial t, \partial Q/\partial x$ etc, you would want to compute the equivalent derivatives to those in your original PDE i.e if your PDE was $$\partial_{t}P=\partial_{x}P$$ then you would want to compute $$\partial_{x} P=\partial_{z}Q \partial_{x}z=\partial_{z}Q,\quad \partial_{t}P=\partial_{z}Q\partial_{t}z+\partial_{t}Q=-\mu \partial_{z}Q+\partial_{t} Q$$

Comment: Yes, this makes a lot of sense, thank you. The only thing I am confused about now is why is the first partial derivative you wrote not equal to: $$ \partial_x P = \partial_z Q\partial_x z + \partial_t Q \partial_x t = \partial_z Q +\frac{1}{\mu}\partial_t Q$$ Since $Q$ is a function of both $z$ and $t$, don't you have to take both partials, as you did for $\partial_t P$?

Comment: Because the second argument is independent of $x$ i.e $\partial_{t} Q \partial_{x} t = \partial_{t} Q \cdot 0 = 0$.